# How to perform two animation in OpenGLES (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Can you please tell me, how to perform both animation like (left to right, move the ball image) and (draw a line and move from top to bottom) at a time in OpenGLES (iPhone)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check this similar thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120962/combining-uiview-animation-blocks-and-opengl-es-rendering

Comment: I tried the source code mentioned in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499077/how-to-draw-a-line-inside-the-fish-movement-opengles-in-iphone